# React onScroll not firing from a parent component

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have a parent component that has no height at first but will grow as children are added. I can scroll up and down after adding the children, but I noticed that handleScroll function is not fired.

Anyone had similar issue?

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
}
handleScroll(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className="parent" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
    {
      this.props.children.map((child)=>{
        <div>{child.name}</div>
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: What is the style of your `div.parent`? Does it contain an attribute of `overflow: scroll;` and it was overflowed indeed when rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the scroll function to your div by this way:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// ...

constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
    const div = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.someRef)
    div.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    const div = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.someRef)
    div.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
handleScroll(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
render() {
  return (
    <div ref="someRef" className="parent">
    {
      this.props.children.map((child)=>{
        <div>{child.name}</div>
      })
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```

..and also please also set the CSS for your div as:

```
.parent{
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```